# Consequences of Uniqueness theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $u$ and $v$ be solutions of the ODE $$\frac{du}{dt}=F(u),~~~t\in \mathbb R$$ for some Lipschitz continuous function $F$ with Lipschitz constant $K$. Show that, If $u$ and $v$ agree at some point $t_0$, then they agree everywhere.

I tried with Uniqueness theorem, but I am not clear how to take the initial condition. What is the role of $K$ here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the Lipschitz condition to conclude the uniqueness property. A global Lipschitz condition as indicated by the existence of the constant $K$ implies that the solutions are defined on all of $\Bbb R$.

Now if $u(t_0)=u_0=v(t_0)$, try to show that then also $u(t_0+s)=v(t_0+s)$.

Comment: So, I have to take the initial point as $t_0$ itself.